# Disposal of old 4mm tape cartridges

Tags: security, tape

In cleaning out my home office, I see that I have a number of old 4mm DAT tapes.  I no longer have a working DAT drive.

Some of these tapes may have information that I do not want to have out in the public.

My question is how do I dispose of these tapes in a safe and secure manner.

Comment: hrm... like 12 years ago the local Best Buy had a bulk tape eraser anyone turning in tape for recycling could use for free.  If you can't find someone with one of those (giant electro-magnet) you could opt for physically breaking the cartridges open then sending it all off to recycling.

Comment: The tape is flammable.  Use a metal trash can outside. If you leave it in the cassette, melt or cook the whole think with a propane torch.  Otherwise, pull out the tape into a pile and light it.  The loose tape might also make a cool experiment in an old microwave oven you don't plan to cook in anymore.

Comment: Fire bad. Plastic fumes worse ><

Answer (score 1):

The 'right' way to do it is likely to use a tape bulk eraser - You're likely going to want a handheld model for cost reasons, though specialised models for dat probably exist. These seem to be *very* rare at the moment. Most of the ones I'm finding on the internet are desktop models and *insanely* expensive.

A quick bit of research on google suggests that they work on DAT tapes but not LTO.

However, considering the impossibility of verifying that the tapes have been properly wiped, I may suggest physical destruction. I wouldn't feed these in a shredder (they may clog up teeth designed for paper, even if you shuck the tape and just feed that in), and most other ideas I can think of seem risky. [Maybe it'll blend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1F_Y_d43v4)

I'd consider checking to see if there's a commercial operation locally that would securely dispose of these for you instead, especially if its a one off thing. Even if its more expensive, it'll ensure you get it done the right way.

This [spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/161704-what-to-do-with-old-tapes) thread has a few ideas - some worse than others

- Cutting up the tapes by hand - seems timeconsuming (I wonder if an angle grinder would do a good job mangling the tapes)
- Microwaves (seems horribly risky)
- Encasement with concrete
- Bleach (how would that even work?)
- VERY strong/large magnets (May work, but the bulk eraser uses a varying magnetic field, not a static one).

Comment: i wonder if putting it sandwiched between two bits of paper would work for a normal shredder ? want to try that now.

Comment: I'd distinctly suggest unless its one of those industrial strength things, and you want it to actually work in future, its a bad idea. Plastic tape + heat can be bad. Least it won't be nitrocellulose...